# Python Code to Find x Prime Numbers w/ For Loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested, primes

I am trying to put together a simple program which could work out n prime numbers. I would like to do this by using a nested for loop, where one would go through the numbers, and another would divide that number by all of the numbers up to it to see if it would be divisible by anything.

The problem I am having is that in the main for loop, I need to start it at 2, seeing as 1 would mess up the system and I don't want it to be considered a prime. For the loop to have a starting number however, it also needs an ending number which is difficult in this instance as it is hard to generate the largest prime that will be needed prior to the loop working.

Here's the program that I am using right now. Where I have marked X is where I need to somehow put an ending number for the For Loop. I guess it would be much simpler if I let the For Loop be completely open, and simply take out anything that '1' would produce in the loop itself, but this feels like cheating and I want to do it right.

```
check = 0
limit = int(input("Enter the amount of Prime Numbers"))
for i in range(2,X):
    check = 0
    if i > 1:
        for j in range(2,i):
            if (i % j) == 0:
                check = 1
    if check == 0:
        print (i)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't something like the sieve of eratosthenes to get your prime numbers? The inner for running for every index is pretty inefficient.

Comment: At the moment you have no way to tell how many you've generated so far. Once you have that, it should be pretty clear what your ending condition is.

Answer (score 1):

You can step through an unlimited amount of numbers using a generator object.

Insert the following somewhere near the top of your code:

```
def infinite_number_generator(initial_value=2):
    """ Generates an infinite amount of numbers """
    i = initial_value
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1
```

What this does is it creates a function for constructing generator objects that "pause" whenever they reach the `yield` statement to "yield" whatever value is specified by the `yield` command, and then continue to execute from the next line beneath the `yield` statement.

Python's own `range` function is itself an example of a generator, and is roughly equivalent to (ignoring the step argument and other peculiarities)

```
def range(start, end):
    i = start
    while i < end:
        yield i
        i += 1
```

So your program would then look like this:

```
def infinite_number_generator(initial_value=2):
    """ Generates an infinite amount of numbers """
    i = initial_value
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

check = 0
limit = int(input("Enter the amount of Prime Numbers"))
for i in infinite_number_generator():
    check = 0
    for j in range(2,i):
        if (i % j) == 0:
            check = 1
    if check == 0:
        print (i)
    if i == limit:
        break
```

I should also point out that the code you provided is buggy - it will never stop printing because there's no checking whether you've found your `limit` number of primes yet or not.

Comment: Hi, This code was a slightly modified version of a code to find all of the primes up to a certain number which I wanted to edit to work for this new purpose. I tried to modify the code that you came up with so that it could be used, but because the function was outside the for loop, it kept continuing separately to the prime generator which meant that it would not print only primes. As of yet I can't find a way to get around this without shifting everything from the loop into the function which is something I want to avoid. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you change `check == 0:` on the second to last line to `check == 1:`? :) edit: never-mind, that's not the problem. The code seems to be printing exclusively primes to me. Though their was a bug with a space in a variable name I've now fixed.

Comment: Okay I've managed to edit the code to work as I needed. This is just done by creating a variable called amount which grows every time a prime number is printed, then adding this to the while loop so that this number doesn't go above limit. Simple haha. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Something I like to see as well :P

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
check = 0
limit = int(input("Enter the amount of Prime Numbers"))
counter = 0
i = 2
while counter < limit:
    check = 0
    if i > 1:
        for j in range(2,i):
            if (i % j) == 0:
                check = 1
    if check == 0:
        counter += 1
        print (i)

    i += 1
```

Comment: Note: using a while loop instead of a for loop is not 'cheating' because a for loop is meant to be used if you know how far you want to count before you start the loop. (If this was what you were referring to as 'cheating' in your question)

Comment: No, that's not what I meant by cheating, I was refering to having something which said if the number is 1, ignore it would be cheating, which could work and leave the for loop open rather than within a boundary.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you start `i` with 2 and always increment by 1, so the `i` will always  remain greater than 1, therefore the test `if i > 1` is useless.
For efficiency you can stop the check at the square of i or i/2 (no divisors in [i/2 + 1, i[ ). 
you can update your code as follow:

```
n = int(input("Enter the amount of Prime Numbers: "))
FoundPrimes = 0
i = 2
while FoundPrimes < n:
    isPrime = True
    for j in range(2,1 + i//2):
        if (i % j) == 0:
            isPrime = False
    if isPrime:
        FoundPrimes += 1
        print(i, end = '\t')
    i += 1
```

Comment: That works fine! Thanks. I think a problem that might be had if you used the square of the previous prime as the boundary is that eventually the number that would follow would be greater than it?

Comment: you must use the square of the current number to check not the prevuious:`for j in range(2,1 + i**0.5)`